# Calculate the integrals $\int_{\partial E}\rho \, dS$ and $\int_{\partial E} \frac{1}{\rho} dS$ over an ellipsoid

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $E= \{\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2} \le 1\}$ be a solid ellipsoid.
For every point $p \in \partial E$ we define $\rho(p)$ to be the distance between the origin and the affine tangent space at $p$.

Calculate the integrals $\displaystyle \int_{\partial E}\rho \, dS$ and $\displaystyle \int_{\partial E} \frac{1}{\rho} \, dS$.

I was able to calculate the first, I got $3\operatorname{Vol}(E)$.  However, I have no idea about the second. To do that I found the perpendicular normal vector $n(p)$ and then $\rho(p) = \langle p,n(p) \rangle$ and used the divergence theorem.

Generally, the solution should be related to those subjects (divergence, flux).

Any tip or advice would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equation of tangent plane at $(x',y',z')$

$$\frac{x'x}{a^2}+\frac{y'y}{b^2}+\frac{z'z}{c^2}=1$$

$$\rho=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\dfrac{x'^2}{a^4}+\dfrac{y'^2}{b^4}+\dfrac{z'^2}{c^4}}}$$

Let $
\begin{pmatrix} x' \\ y' \\ z' \end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
  a\sin u \cos v \\
  b\sin u \sin v \\
  c\cos u
\end{pmatrix}$

\begin{align*}
  dS &=
  abc\sqrt{\dfrac{x'^2}{a^4}+\dfrac{y'^2}{b^4}+\dfrac{z'^2}{c^4}}
  \sin u \,du \, dv \\
  \oint_{\partial E} \rho \, dS &=
  abc \int_{0}^{2\pi} dv \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin u\, du \\
  &= 4\pi abc
\end{align*}

For the second integral
\begin{align*}
  \oint_{\partial E} \frac{1}{\rho} \, dS &=
  abc \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi}
  \left(
    \frac{\sin^2 u \cos^2 v}{a^2}+
    \frac{\sin^2 u \sin^2 v}{b^2}+
    \frac{\cos^2 u}{a^2}
  \right)
  \sin u\, du \, dv \\ &=
  abc \int_{0}^{2\pi}
  \left(
    \frac{4\cos^2 v}{3a^2}+
    \frac{4\sin^2 v}{3b^2}+
    \frac{2}{3c^2}
  \right) dv \\ &=
  \frac{4\pi abc}{3}
  \left(
    \frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}+\frac{1}{c^2}
  \right)
\end{align*}