# Compute $\iint \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2x^2+b^2y^2+c^2z^2}}dS$ over surface of ellipsoid $ax^2+by^2+cz^2=1$ using Gauss's divergence theorem.

Tags: vector-analysis

As unit normal on the surface is 
$$\hat{n} = \frac{ax\hat{i}+by\hat{j}+cz\hat{k}}{\sqrt{a^2x^2+b^2y^2+c^2z^2}}$$
I took 
$$\overrightarrow{F} = \frac{\hat{i}}{ax}$$

so that
$$\overrightarrow{F}\cdot \hat{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2x^2+b^2y^2+c^2z^2}}$$

Hence the given integral is equal to

$$ \int \overrightarrow{F}\cdot dS = \int div \overrightarrow{F} dV = \int -\frac{1}{ax^2} dV $$ over ellipsoid.

I can't think of any method to compute this last integral. Please give some ideas.

Comment: The problem with your calculation is that $\vec{F}$ that you picked is not defined at all points inside the ellipsoid (i.e., it is not defined on the plane $x=0$).   Therefore, you cannot use the Divergence Theorem.  One possible choice is $\vec{F}:=\vec{r}=x\hat{i}+y\hat{j}+z\hat{k}$, so that $\vec{F}\cdot \hat{n}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a^2x^2+b^2y^2+c^2z^2}}$ on the ellipsoid's surface.  As $\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{r}=3$, the integral is just three times the volume of the ellipsoid, which is $\dfrac{4\pi}{3}\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt{abc}}\right)$.  Multiply that by $3$ to get the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should choose suitable $\mathbf{F}$,

\begin{align}
  \mathbf{F} &= \frac{(x,y,z)}{ax^2+by^2+cz^2} \\
  \nabla \cdot \mathbf{F} &=
  \frac{1}{ax^2+by^2+cz^2} \\
\end{align}

Using reduced coordinates:

\begin{align}
  (x,y,z) &=
  \left(
    \frac{x'}{\sqrt{a}},
    \frac{y'}{\sqrt{b}},
    \frac{z'}{\sqrt{c}}
  \right) \\
  dV &= \frac{dx' \, dy' \, dz'}{\sqrt{abc}} \\
  \iiint \nabla \cdot \mathbf{F} \, dV &=
  \iiint \color{red}{\frac{1}{x'^2+y'^2+z'^2}} \times
  \frac{dx' \, dy' \, dz'}{\sqrt{abc}} \\
  &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{abc}} \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi \int_0^{\pi} \sin \theta \, d\theta
  \int_0^1 \color{red}{\frac{1}{r^2}} \times r^2 \, dr \\
  &= \frac{4\pi}{\sqrt{abc}}
\end{align}

Compare the results of another answer of mine [**here**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2147049/calculate-the-integrals-int-partial-e-rho-ds-and-int-partial-e-fr/2147292#2147292).