# Evaluate $I=\iint\limits_S f(x;y;z)\ dS$ over an ellipsoid

Tags: calculus, integration, surface-integrals

> Evaluate the following surface integral $I$
>   $$
> \begin{aligned}
> &I=\iint\limits_S f(x;y;z)\ dS\ \ \text{where}\\
> &\text{$S$ is an ellipsoid}\ \ \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1\ \ \text{and}\ \ f=\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{a^4}+\frac{y^2}{b^4}+\frac{z^2}{c^4}}
> \end{aligned}
> $$

I used a substitution for $x, y$ and $z$.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\begin{cases}
x=a\sin\theta\cos\phi\\
y=b\sin\theta\sin\phi\\
z=c\cos\theta
\end{cases},\ \ \ 0\leqslant\theta\leqslant\pi,\ \ 0\leqslant\phi<2\pi
\end{aligned}
$$
Then, I tried to calculate $dS$. 
$$
\begin{aligned}
&r=r(x,y,z),\ \ dS=\sqrt{|G|}\ d\phi d\theta,\ \ \text{where $G$ is a Gramian matrix}\\
&G=\begin{pmatrix}
(r'_\phi,r'_\phi) & (r'_\phi,r'_\theta)\\
(r'_\theta,r'_\phi) & (r'_\theta,r'_\theta)
\end{pmatrix}
\end{aligned}
$$
However, the calculations of $G$ became very tough, and now I doubt that it was the right way to solve this problem.
So, the question is how should I approach this problem?

Comment: Let us assume $u^2= \frac{x^2}{a^2}$, $v^2= \frac{y^2}{b^2}$, $w^2= \frac{z^2}{c^2}$. So that the surface becomes sphere.

Comment: Then, the function $f$ will get very complicated and the final integral will be insurmountable. I already tried this :(

Comment: Related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2147049/calculate-the-integrals-int-partial-e-rho-ds-and-int-partial-e-fr).

Comment: Thanks! I should not have used a Gramian matrix but a vector product instead to calculate $dS$. Now, I solved this problem.